# Ice faces datapaginator doesn´t work

Tags: java, jsf, icefaces-1.8, data-paging

I have a problem with an ice:dataPaginator.

It shows correctly the number of rows in my datatable also shows correctly the current page, but when I press the next page icon nothings happens, in others words if I have 23 rows it shows correctly the firts 20 but when I press ">" for the next page the last 3 rows are never show.
This is my datatable and dataPaginator code on my .jspf view, I´m using icefaces 1.8

```
<ice:dataTable binding="#{ViewSubastas.tablaLotes}" id="tableLotes" rows="20" value="#{ViewSubastas.listaLotesSubasta}" var="lote" width="100%">
 <ice:column style="width:30px">
     <f:facet name="header">
       <ice:outputText value="#{labels.labelLote}"/>
     </f:facet>
     <ice:outputText rendered="#{not lote.seleccionado}" style="text-align:center " value="#{lote.loteId.nroLote}"/>
     <ice:outputText rendered="#{lote.seleccionado}" styleClass="filaConsolidado" style="text-align:center " value="#{lote.loteId.nroLote}"/>
  </ice:column>
.
.
.
(Others columns)
.
.
.
</ice:dataTable>

<ice:dataPaginator actionListener="#{ViewSubastas.VerificarPagi}" for="tableLotes" paginatorMaxPages="20" pageCountVar="pageCount" pageIndexVar="pageIndex" rowsCountVar="rowsCount">
  <f:facet name="first">
     <ice:graphicImage url="./resources/css/sew/css-images/icoFlechaPrimero.png"/>
  </f:facet>
  <f:facet name="last">
      <ice:graphicImage url="./resources/css/sew/css-images/icoFlechaUltimo.png"/>
  </f:facet>
  <f:facet name="previous">
      <ice:graphicImage url="./resources/css/sew/css-images/icoFlechaAnterior.png"/>
  </f:facet>
  <f:facet name="next">
      <ice:graphicImage url="./resources/css/sew/css-images/icoFlechaSiguiente.png"/>
  </f:facet>
  <ice:outputFormat styleClass="standard" value="{2} #{labels.paginLotes}. #{labels.pagina} {0} #{labels.de} {1}.">
    <f:param value="#{pageIndex}"/>
    <f:param value="#{pageCount}"/>
    <f:param value="#{rowsCount}"/>
  </ice:outputFormat>
</ice:dataPaginator>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the problem, in my .jspf page there was another ice:datatable with the same id "tableLotes" so the datapaginator didn´t know which to obey